# Counting the operations of a problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a square matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, it has a LU decomposition. $L$ and $U$ are triangular and $L$ has ones on the main diagonal.

I'm counting the number of operations for $(U^TL^TLU)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, which is $A^TA\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$.

What is the correct number of operations for this system? There are two back and two forward substitutions in the process as one can solve this as

$$U^T \mathbf{x_1}=\mathbf{b}\quad (1)$$
$$L^T \mathbf{x_2}=\mathbf{x_1}\quad (2)$$
$$L \mathbf{x_3}=\mathbf{x_2}\quad (3)$$
$$U \mathbf{x_4}=\mathbf{x_3}\quad (4)$$

where $\mathbf{x_4} = \mathbf{x}$.

My solutions are $n^2-n$ for solving equations 2 and 3 (because of ones on the diagonal) and $n^2$ for 1 and 4, that equals $2(n^2-n)+2n^2$ operations.

But the official solution to this problem is $2n^2$. what am I doing wrong?

I count operations like this, for example
$$(k_1\cdot\alpha + k_2\cdot\beta) + \gamma = \delta$$ 
does two multiplications and two summations, therefore four operations to calculate $\delta$.

Comment: $L$ and $U$ should be _triangular_ (if they were diagonal and $L$ as requested then $A=U$ is diagonal and solvable in $n$ ops)

Comment: My mistake, I corrected it.